# The best way to keep Tasks' Priority (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There is class **Task.cs**

```
public class Task
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Priority { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DateCreation { get; set; }

    public string DateTarget { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

}
```

and its property `Priority` can have 4 different values: 0 - low, 1 - normal, 2 - high, 3 - extreme.
What is the best way to keep these values? Should I create `class Priority`, or just create table `Priority` in my database and set these values in or use `List` maybe?
It's my first attempt to create Asp.Net MVC application so I'm not sure what  way is better.

Comment: If the values are unlikely to change, consider making it an `enum`

Comment: Are you asking where you should keep the Task options so they can be rendered in the view e.g. Drop Down?

Comment: You can look at `enum` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: May you explain me please, where I need to create `enum` ? In class `Task` or somewhere else?

Comment: @Heidel You must create our enum in common layer that access to it in other layer such as DAL,UI,Service Layer

Comment: `public enum TaskPriority { low = 0, normal = 1, etc }` and in the model `public TaskPriority Priority { get; set; }`

Comment: @Heidel enums are like named constants, that make code much readable and you can avoid hardcoding numbers in your code.Also compiler can give you validation for values, if you are passing them to functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stephen Muecke said, you need to use enum.You can create enum in a layer that accessible from another layers(UI,DAL,Service).